# Issue with if statement on code for making a git pull in all subfolders with .git directory in it

Tags: bash

I am working on a bash function. The function should be able to print out the possible directories which will be effected and should ask if you really want to execute the command.

Im having some issues with the if statements which are in the code.

```
dogitpull () {
  for i in */.git; do ( echo $i; cd $i/..; ); done
  echo -n 'Are you sure? (y/n) '
  read answer
  if $answer == 'n' ; then
    echo '---CANCELED---'
  elif $answer == 'y' ; then
    echo '---------------------------'
    for d in */.git; do ( echo $d; cd $d/..; git pull; echo '-------'; ); done
  else
    echo '---Please answer with y/n---'
fi
}
```

Its possible I am overlooking something very simple, but I could also be completely wrong.

Maybe theres a much easier solution than my attempt.

Issue output:

```
...
Are you sure? (y/n) y
-bash: y: command not found
-bash: y: command not found
---Please answer with y/n---
```

Comment: ??? Which are the issues?

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ is your friend

Comment: Use the `[` operator in the conditionals: `if [ $answer == 'n' ] ; then`

Comment: @Poshi Thanks, that worked

Comment: Hummm... better if I put this into an answer,so the question does not remains officially unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [ operator in the conditionals:

```
if [ $answer == 'n' ] ; then
```

By leaving out the `[` operator, you are trying to execute the command `$answer` with parameters `== 'n' ]`, and the result of this command is what gets tested. Because you introduced `y` as answer to the `read` operation, `y` is tried to be executed. You don't have a `y` command on your system, hence the `command not found` complain.